# How do I prove this claim using the contrapositive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

For all positive integers $x$, if $x^2-4x+1$ is even, then $x$ is odd.

Steps I took:

So, I know that the contrapositive of $(a \Rightarrow b)$ is $(\neg b \Rightarrow \neg a)$

Proof:

We prove the contrapositive: if $x$ is even, then $x^2-4x+1$ is odd.

Assume that $x$ is even, then $x=2k$ such that $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k \neq 0$

Then...

My problem is that I am used to proving an implication from left to right. In this case scenario, I would usually take the left hand side and manipulate it algebraically till I arrived at the same end result as the right hand side.
I seem to have hit a brick wall here in that regard. A hint in the right direction to get me towards the right solution (proof) would be best.

Comment: Substitute $2k$ for $x$ in the expression $x^2 - 4x + 1$.  You want to write the result in the form $2u + 1$, where $u$ is an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ is even, then $x^2$ is even, and $-4x$ is even too. And of course $1$ is always odd. The sum of two even numbers and an odd one is always odd.

Comment: I thought I have to deduce the right hand side of the implication by manipulating the left hand side. No?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: No, you just have to conclude the desired conclusion _somehow_, where along the way you're allowed to assume the assumption is true when and if you need that. "Manipulating the assumption" is a particular strategy that will work in some (but by no means all) cases, but it is not an inherent part of what it means to be a valid proof.

Comment: Do I need to include a lemma that proves that the sum of two even numbers and an odd number is aways odd?

Someone above mentioned that I can just substitute $2k$ into the righthand side ($x^2-4x+1$). Is that also a viable alternative?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: Whether you need to prove that separately depends on what you can assume that the reader of your proof already knows. In a classroom setting this mostly comes down to knowing what the teacher _expects_ -- that's not really a mathematical issue, but one about what the conventions of the class is. Substituting $x=2k$ in the polynomial is certainly also an option -- but again it will depend on the teacher whether it counts as a better solution (because it looks more formal), or a worse one (because it demonstrates less intuitive understanding of the problem).

Comment: I am studying discrete math from MIT OCW and the Lecture Notes say: "...instead of starting with ZFC, we're going to take a huge set of axioms as our foundation: we'll accept all familiar facts from high school math!" 

I remember even+odd, even+even, odd+odd and etc. relations from the SATs. Something tells me that I can use that as an assumption in my proof then.

I have finished writing up the proof. Would you be willing to look over it for me?